# Can we change the linked-to question here, folks?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

This question here was rightly closed as a duplicate:

- [Which is grammatically correct: "There is tea and juice" or "There are tea and juice"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375299/which-is-grammatically-correct-there-is-tea-and-juice-or-there-are-tea-and-j/)

It has currently been linked to the following three other questions:

1. [Should I say "there is a handful of..." or "there are a handful of...."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58676/should-i-say-there-is-a-handful-of-or-there-are-a-handful-of)
2. ["There is a lot of food and fruit" vs. "there are a lot of food and fruit"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141192/there-is-a-lot-of-food-and-fruit-vs-there-are-a-lot-of-food-and-fruit)
3. ["There Is"/"There are" depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not)

These appear in a different order on the original page. Now my feeling is that numbers (1) and (2) here are about Determiners and mass nouns. The Determiners in these examples have an impact on whether we see plural or singular verb inflection. Another main issue is the mass nouns involved. The coordination is a supplementary issue in only one of the questions and not a main concern of either of these questions or answers.

In contrast, the third question is a genuine duplicate because the main issue in these two questions is the coordination appearing as the Complement of the verb *BE*. Can we change the links so that the question is only linked to number (3), please? It would reduce the spagetti junction of question links and also provide a more reliable final landing page for readers.

Comment: I was going to respond initially saying that this just seems like a very low impact request for a lot of developer effort; it's already handled automatically, and people can read just fine. But it seems like the SE development team had already thought of this as a problem and have 'fixed' it. I'm not sure if it is a good fix (how many people have gold stars for badges). But maybe a mod can do what you request.

Comment: Well it seems you're not talking to me. But I am pleased you undeleted your answer. And I repeat, I did not DV it, that's the only reason I can come up with that would explain your silence.